# Multiprocessing acting up in Python 3

Tags: python, multithreading, python-3.x, multiprocessing, cracking

I was messing around with a zip file cracker and decided to use the multiprocessing module to speed the process up. It was a complete pain since it was my first time using the module and I don't even fully understand it yet.  However, I got it to work.

The problem is that it doesn't complete the word list; it just stops at random puts during the word list, and if the password is found it continues to go through the word list instead of just stopping the process.

Does anyone know why it's exhibiting this behaviour?

**Source Code For ZipFile Cracker**

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import multiprocessing as mp
import zipfile # Handeling the zipfile
import sys # Command line arguments, and quiting application
import time # To calculate runtime

def usage(program_name):
    print("Usage: {0} <path to zipfile> <dictionary>".format(program_name))
    sys.exit(1)

def cracker(password):
    try:
        zFile.extractall(pwd=password)
        print("[+] Password Found! : {0}".format(password.decode('utf-8')))
        pool.close()
    except:
        pass

def main():
    global zFile
    global pool

    if len(sys.argv) < 3:
        usage(sys.argv[0])

    zFile = zipfile.ZipFile(sys.argv[1])

    print("[*] Started Cracking")

    startime = time.time()
    pool = mp.Pool()

    for i in open(sys.argv[2], 'r', errors='ignore'):
        pswd = bytes(i.strip('\n'), 'utf-8')
        pool.apply_async(cracker, (pswd,))

    print (pswd)
    runtime =  round(time.time() - startime, 5)
    print ("[*] Runtime:", runtime, 'seconds')
    sys.exit(0)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's an implementation of the advice from [@phihag's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31350837/4279) and [@Equality 7-2521's answers](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31351538/4279):

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
"""Brute force zip password.

Usage: brute-force-zip-password <zip archive> <passwords>
"""
import sys
from multiprocessing import Pool
from time import monotonic as timer
from zipfile import ZipFile

def init(archive): # run at the start of a worker process
    global zfile
    zfile = ZipFile(open(archive, 'rb')) # open file in each process once

def check(password):
    assert password
    try:
        with zfile.open(zfile.infolist()[0], pwd=password):
            return password # assume success
    except Exception as e:
        if e.args[0] != 'Bad password for file':
            # assume all other errors happen after the password was accepted
            raise RuntimeError(password) from e

def main():
    if len(sys.argv) != 3:
        sys.exit(__doc__) # print usage

    start = timer()
    # decode passwords using the preferred locale encoding
    with open(sys.argv[2], errors='ignore') as file, \
         Pool(initializer=init, initargs=[sys.argv[1]]) as pool: # use all CPUs
        # check passwords encoded using utf-8
        passwords = (line.rstrip('\n').encode('utf-8') for line in file)
        passwords = filter(None, passwords) # filter empty passwords
        for password in pool.imap_unordered(check, passwords, chunksize=100):
            if password is not None:  # found
                print("Password: '{}'".format(password.decode('utf-8')))
                break
        else:
            sys.exit('Unable to find password')
    print('Runtime: %.5f seconds' % (timer() - start,))

if __name__=="__main__":
    main()
```

Note:

- each worker process has its own `ZipFile` object and the zip file is opened once per process: it should make it more portable (Windows support)  and improve time performance
- the content is not extracted: `check(password)` tries to open and immediately closes an archive member on success: it is safer and it should improve time performance (no need to create directories, etc)
- all errors except `'Bad password for file'` while decrypting the archive member are assumed to happen *after* the password is accepted: the rational is to avoid silencing unexpected errors -- each exception should be considered individually
- `check(password)` expects nonempty passwords
- `chunksize` parameter may drastically improve performance
- a rare `for`/`else` syntax is used, to report cases when the password is not  found
- the `with`-statement calls `pool.terminate()` for you

Comment: Sorry to bother you but the script u wrote works fine with small word lists but with large word lists this error is raised:
    RuntimeError: File <zipfile.ZipInfo object at 0x02734510> is encrypted, password required for extraction
any thoughts?

Comment: The same error is now raised for any word list.

Comment: @NightHawk: the code works as is. I've tested it with millions passwords. Make sure you haven't deleted `pwd=` part.

Comment: I created a new file and copy and pasted the code you shared with me.
Here is a screenshot highlighting the 'pwd=' bit and the error i get in the terminal.
https://www.dropbox.com/s/i5xvtnbwl5nv0rx/Screen%20Shot%202015-07-11%20at%204.10.34%20AM.png?dl=0
Thanks again and sorry for being annoying <3
Note: the word list I used is just 500 words.

Comment: @NightHawk: your input has empty passwords. I've updated the code.

Comment: so sorry to do this but I know get the error zlib.error: Error -3 while decompressing data: invalid distance too far back

Comment: @NightHawk: If the `zlib.error` can happen only for a valid password then catch it and return `password` or raise an exception mentioning the password. It seems unrelated to `multiprocessing`.

Comment: I upgrade python to latest version everything runs great now. Without your code run-time for a specific zip file would take 120 seconds with a exceptionally large word list now it only takes 30 seconds. Many thanks sir.

Comment: @NightHawk: I've updated the code, to avoid trying to extract all archive members for each password. It should improve time performance.

Answer (score 2):

You are terminating your program too early. To test this out, add a harmless `time.sleep(10)` in the `cracker` method and observe your program still terminating within a second.

Call [`join`](https://docs.python.org/dev/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing.pool.Pool.join) to wait for the pool to finish:

```
pool = mp.Pool()
for i in open(sys.argv[2], 'r', errors='ignore'):
    pswd = bytes(i.strip('\n'), 'utf-8')
    pool.apply_async(cracker, (pswd,))

pool.close()  # Indicate that no more data is coming
pool.join()   # Wait for pool to finish processing

runtime =  round(time.time() - startime, 5)
print ("[*] Runtime:", runtime, 'seconds')
sys.exit(0)
```

Additionally, once you find the right password, calling `close` just indicates that no more future tasks are coming - all tasks already submitted will still be done. Instead, call [`terminate`](https://docs.python.org/dev/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing.pool.Pool.terminate) to kill the pool without processing any more tasks.

Furthermore, depending on the implementation details of `multiprocessing.Pool`, the global variable `pool` may not be available when you need it (and its value isn't serializable anyways). To solve this problem, you can use a callback, as in

```
def cracker(password):
    try:
        zFile.extractall(pwd=password)
    except RuntimeError:
        return
    return password

 def callback(found):
     if found:
         pool.terminate()
 ...
 pool.apply_async(cracker, (pswd,), callback=cb)
```

Of course, since you now look at the result all the time, `apply` is not the right way to go. Instead, you can write your code using [`imap_unordered`](https://docs.python.org/dev/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing.pool.Pool.imap_unordered):

```
with open(sys.argv[2], 'r', errors='ignore') as passf, \
         multiprocessing.Pool() as pool:
     passwords = (line.strip('\n').encode('utf-8') for line in passf)
     for found in pool.imap_unordered(cracker, passwords):
         if found:
             break
```

Instead of using globals, you may also want to open the zip file (and create a `ZipFile` object) in each process, by using an [`initializer`](https://docs.python.org/dev/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing.pool.Pool) for the pool. Even better (and way faster), forgo all of the I/O in the first place and read just the bytes you need once and then pass them on to the children.

Comment: Thanks phihag, multiprocessing now works fine thanks to you but i ran into another problem. When I run the application a strange error is raised saying that zFile is not defined even thou I made it as a global variable and when I try to pass the zFile object to cracker the function doesn't even run. I would appreciate your help.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: @NightHawk: Please see my answer, specifically the advice to _explicitly pass resources to child processes_.

Comment: @NightHawk I've amended my answer as well, with more of an explanation. See the other answers for the full code.

Comment: I keep getting random errors when i use bigger word lists.
one of them is:
zlib.error: Error -3 while decompressing data: invalid distance too far back

Answer (score 1):

phihag's answer is the correct solution.

I just wanted to provide an additional detail regarding calling `terminate()` when you've found the correct password.  The `pool` variable in `cracker()` was not defined when I ran the code.  So trying to invoke it from there simply threw an exception:

```
NameError: name 'pool' is not defined
```

(My `fork()` experience is weak, so I don't completely understand why the global `zFile` is copied to the child processes successfully while `pool` is not. Even if it were copied, it would not be the same `pool` in the parent process, right?  So any methods invoked on it would have no effect on the *real* pool in the parent process.  Regardless, I prefer [this](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html#all-start-methods) advice listed within the `multiprocessing` module's *Programming guidelines* section: **Explicitly pass resources to child processes**.)

My suggestion is to make `cracker()` return the password if it is correct, otherwise return `None`.  Then pass a callback to `apply_async()` that records the correct password, as well as terminating the pool.  Here's my take at modifying your code to do this:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import multiprocessing as mp
import zipfile # Handeling the zipfile
import sys # Command line arguments, and quiting application
import time # To calculate runtime
import os

def usage(program_name):
    print("Usage: {0} <path to zipfile> <dictionary>".format(program_name))
    sys.exit(1)

def cracker(zip_file_path, password):
    print('[*] Starting new cracker (pid={0}, password="{1}")'.format(os.getpid(), password))

    try:
        time.sleep(1) # XXX: to simulate the task taking a bit of time
        with zipfile.ZipFile(zip_file_path) as zFile:
            zFile.extractall(pwd=bytes(password, 'utf-8'))
        return password
    except:
        return None

def main():
    if len(sys.argv) < 3:
        usage(sys.argv[0])

    print('[*] Starting main (pid={0})'.format(os.getpid()))

    zip_file_path = sys.argv[1]
    password_file_path = sys.argv[2]
    startime = time.time()
    actual_password = None

    with mp.Pool() as pool:
        def set_actual_password(password):
            nonlocal actual_password
            if password:
                print('[*] Found password; stopping future tasks')
                pool.terminate()
                actual_password = password

        with open(password_file_path, 'r', errors='ignore') as password_file:
            for pswd in password_file:
                pswd = pswd.strip('\n')
                pool.apply_async(cracker, (zip_file_path, pswd,), callback=set_actual_password)

        pool.close()
        pool.join()

    if actual_password:
        print('[*] Cracked password: "{0}"'.format(actual_password))
    else:
        print('[*] Unable to crack password')
    runtime =  round(time.time() - startime, 5)
    print("[*] Runtime:", runtime, 'seconds')
    sys.exit(0)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```